# Python: Remove 0s from floats in string

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I'm looking for a way, to remove all useless zeros from all floats in a string.
So I'd turn `1.0*2.40*abc+1` to `1*2.4*abc+1`.
I had two ways to do so now, one fixes the other one's problem:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\.?0+\b', "", my_string)
#Problem: It shorts 10 to 1 (for example)

re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\.0+\b', "", my_string)
#Problem: It doesn't short 2.40 (for example)
```

*If you don't know, what I'm talking about, feel free to ask.*

Comment: Do you want to shorten individual floats or entire expressions like `1.0*2.40*abc+1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a regular expression substitution, using a function as substitution:

```
repl=lambda x: x.group(1) + (x.group(2).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
re.sub('(?<!\d)(\d+)(\.\d*)(?!\d)',repl,string)
```

it is certainly easier than much more complex REs. The lookaheads now are optional, but they do not change the matches you get.

```
>>> for testcase in ('1','1.','1.0','1.01','1.01000','0.00','0.100','1.0*2.40*abc+1','100.000','100.0100','20.020','200.'):
...     print('{:16s} --> {}'.format(testcase, re.sub('(?<!\d)(\d+)(\.\d*)(?!\d)',repl,testcase)))
...
1                --> 1
1.               --> 1
1.0              --> 1
1.01             --> 1.01
1.01000          --> 1.01
0.00             --> 0
0.100            --> 0.1
1.0*2.40*abc+1   --> 1*2.4*abc+1
100.000          --> 100
100.0100         --> 100.01
20.020           --> 20.02
200.             --> 200
```

Comment: That changed like - nothing?

Comment: Which one? I don't find a working one.. Update your post pls

Comment: Ah - I see. But integers are getting points behind them (even visible in your test: 100.0 -> 100.)

Comment: This one fails on `.10000000` (note the lack of a digit before the decimal point).

Comment: @Unknown - That is something you are doing elsewhere. Neither mescalinum's nor my regular expression adds a decimal point.

Comment: @DavidHammen I'm not american, so 0.1 is written with a leading zero which is not optional. Also, every scientific software I know uses this format with the leading zero.

Comment: Well, that's my bad again, sorry for that. But, "100.0" > "100." . And that can't be my fault, cause my program is two lines long, and does nothing else than importing re, and running his command.

Comment: @Unknown: I changed to something simpler, but which works better

Comment: @mescalinum, Personally, I'm not thrilled with the `rstrip('.')` Mathematically, there's a difference between 3 and 3.0. The first is an element of ℤ, the latter, an element of ℝ. On another personal note, I won't touch python 3 because of how 3/2 has changed meaning (and value).

Comment: The OP has clearly asked that `1.0*2.40*abc+1` should become `1*2.4*abc+1`. Nobody has talked about number theory here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a look-behind pattern (the `(?<=...) construct). That won't work here. What you  need to do is to look for "insignificant" zeros. The two zeros in 100. The last two zeros in 100.0100 are not significant. Some things to watch out for:

- 100 -> 100
  This must remain untouched (as of course must '0').
- 100.0000 -> 100
  Here want want to delete the trailing zeros and the decimal point.
- 100.0100 -> 100.01 
  Here want want to retain the decimal point and all fractional digits up to the '1'.
- .1000 -> .1
  Here there are no leading digits before the decimal point.

A (not quite) simple regular expression will do the trick:

```
re.sub('(\d\.|\.\d*[1-9])0+(?!\d)',r'\1',string)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/9MVIlC

Comment: It's nearly working. But if I enter an integer, it puts a point behind it. (200 > 200.) And 20.020 => 20.200000000

Comment: it also fails with one of the cases you listed: `re.sub("(\d\.|\.\d*[1-9])0+",r'\1','100.0100')` ---> `'100.100'`

Comment: @mescalinum - Fixed that. I needed a zero-length forward lookahead at the end of the expression.

Comment: @mescalinum - BTW, I didn't steal that from your answer. I tested my original answer, and oops! Didn't always work. I needed to make sure the zeros were at the end of the number.

Comment: @Unknown, this does not add any zeros, or a decimal point. You are doing that elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidHammen > I know, I can't edit my post anymore. But, it turns 2.020 into 2.0, and that's wrong.

Comment: @Unknown - You asked about removing zeros, not the decimal point. My code does not add a decimal point to 100: `100->100` . It strips the trailing zeros from 100.000: `100.000 -> 100.` There's a big difference between `100` and `100.`. The first represents an integer, the second, a real number. You can see this in python 2, where `3/2`evaluates to 1 but `3./2.` evaluates to 1.5.

Comment: @Unknown - I updated the ideone link. It does not turn 2.020 into 2.0. It turns it into 2.02.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the string coming from? Perhaps it is better generating it in the format you want from the beginning rather than trying to parse it afterwards.  For example...and not a complete solution, since I have no clue the possible range of values you will have.  Check out Python's Mini Formatting Language on the Python site for your version of python.  The numbers etc in the format section can obviously be replaced with variables

```
>>> "{:3.0f}*{:3.1f}*{}+{:<3.0F}".format(1.000,2.40000,"abc",1e0)
'  1*2.4*abc+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is (IMO) the simplest way to do it, avoiding complex regexes. Assumes that all your expressions are delimited by +, -, * or /.

```
def strip(s):
    if s.find('.') != -1:
        s= s.rstrip('0')
        if s[-1] == '.': s = s[:-1]
        return s
    else:
        return s

s = raw_input() + '+'
accum = ''
out = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] in "+-/*":
        out = out + strip(accum) + s[i] 
        accum = ''
    else:
        accum = accum + s[i]
print out[:-1]
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you don't want to use `re` library you can simply do this. It's an old trick.

```
string = <your_string_with_zeroes>
string_new = []
for i in list(string):
    if i!='0':
        string_new.append(i)

print(''.join(string_new))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this remove all 0s from the string, even useful ones like - 10 ?

Comment: In fact it wouldn't remove *any*, because `0 != '0'`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe >> We're talking about strings. So "0" == "0". An int doesn't matter ^^

Comment: @Unknown the original edit was *not* talking about strings, not to mention the fact that this answer is still broken

Comment: @Unknown After jonsharpe's comment, an edit has been made. However, I realize this answer is not the fix.